# Calling private native method using reflection

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, native

I have this piece of code in my app (I'm invoking a `private` **`native`** method)

```
 Method m;
 try {
     m = Time.class.getDeclaredMethod("format1", String.class);
     m.setAccessible(true);
     return (String) m.invoke((Time) this, format);

 } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

which `Time` is `android.text.format.time` class, and I run this code in a class which extends `Time`.

The problem is, I'm getting no errors inside my app, and then my app suddenly closes itself. (without force close)

In logcat, I'm having these:

```
A/libc(9193): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)
I/DEBUG(15804): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG(15804): Build fingerprint: 'google/soju/crespo:4.0.4/IMM76D/299849:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG(15804): pid: 9193, tid: 9193  >>> com.myapp <<<
I/DEBUG(15804): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
I/DEBUG(15804):  r0 00000000  r1 bed564a0  r2 bed565a1  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG(15804):  r4 4008a55c  r5 00000000  r6 bed565cc  r7 016b58b9
I/DEBUG(15804):  r8 bed565a1  r9 4020b9a4  10 bed5647c  fp bed5663c
I/DEBUG(15804):  ip ffffff1c  sp bed5639c  lr 4006c58d  pc 4006c14c  cpsr 20000030
...
```

Any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: What's the Java method signature for format1, and how are you declaring the native function in your JNI implementation?

Comment: There's a reason this method is private. It relies on several private fields that need to be initialized properly before invoking it.

Comment: @Roman Guy: But according to android src for this class, I just call it when I do such initializations. My class extends Time, but I'm removed the native function and trying to call it exactly when it is called in Time class.

Comment: @KeyhanAsghari Obviously you aren't succeeding in that endeavor. Why are you doing this at all?

Comment: I'm localizing google calendar app, and I need to work with Time class.

Comment: Private implementation is private because you shouldn't use it.  Ignoring you even getting it to work on whatever device you are on, you have *no* idea how this will work on any other device or any other version of the platform (or future versions of the platform), or if that will even exist at all.  You are just setting yourself up for continual pain.  Just don't do this.  Please.

Comment: Yeah, I chose another way. Thanks everybody.